# pass the content of one data frame to another in r

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, case-when

I am currently learning R in order to write my thesis in my university.

In my project I have one data frame with 2 columns and 6001 rows. In my first column I have numbers from 10000,9999,9998 until 4000 and in the second column I have numeric elements. In my mind I want to do something very simple. I want to create a second data frame with half the size of the original data frame, that contains the even numbers of the first column with the numeric from the second column.

I tried some scripts that didn't go as planned. My first script was:`ifelse(tkk[1] %% 2 == 0, tkal<-tkk, 0)`. And then I tried this one: 
`tkal <-case_when((tkk[1]%%2 ==0)~ tkk)`. But both of my scripts didn't run or have not the results that I wanted.

Does any of you have a solution or a better idea so I could solve this simple task?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `tkk2 <- dplyr::filter(tkk, first_column %% 2 == 0)`

Note that you don't need any condition on the second column since R assumes an unique type for a column in `data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you @ANG for your time and helping me solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

If tkk is your dataframe you can do the following

```
tkk[tkk[,1]%%2==0,]
```

This returns all columns of the data frame where the first column has even values.

Code I used:

```
tkk=data.frame(1:20,rep(1,20))
tkk[tkk[,1]%%2==0,]
#2      2          1
#4      4          1
#6      6          1
#8      8          1
#10    10          1
#12    12          1
#14    14          1
#16    16          1
#18    18          1
#20    20          1
```

Comment: Assuming that column 1 is named "my_col", one could do something equivalent but a little easier to read: `subset(tkk, my_col %% 2 == 0)`

Comment: Thank you very much @jdobres. I used your line to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to subset. I suggest using `which()` in case you have NA values.

```
tkal <- tkk[which(tkk[[1]] %% 2 ==0),]
```